# Laravel Validation: required_if condition always passing

Tags: php, laravel

As per laravel validation documentation:

required_if:anotherfield,value,...
The field under validation must be present and not empty if the anotherfield field is equal to any value.

Here is my test:

```
    $validator = Validator::make([
        'assessment' => [
            'hasConfirmation' => 0,
            'expiredDate' => "12/2020"
        ]
    ],
        [
            'assessment.hasConfirmation' => Rule::in([0, 1, null]),
            'assessment.expiredDate' => Rule::requiredIf('assessment.hasConfirmation' === 1),

        ]);

   $validator->passes(); // always return true
```

I would expect that since I am not passing 1, this test should fail. But this test always passes

Comment: you are checking if a string literal is equal to an integer 1 .... what you have there is  `...requiredIf(false)`

Comment: As per laravel validation documentation: "This methods accepts a boolean" so it should be fail even if you are right

Comment: right and you are passing it `false`, what do you think passing it `false` means?

Comment: I tought that if it false, then it should fail. if it true it should pass. what do I miss?

Comment: you are saying this field is required IF something ... since you are passing `false` as something, you are saying it is not required

Comment: How can I make a validation that a field will be required only if a some_field is equal to true, otherwise the validation should fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure with `requiredIf` that returns a boolean to determine if the 'required' rule should be applied:

```
$data = [
    'assessment' => [
        'hasConfirmation' => 0,
        'expiredDate' => "12/2020"
    ]
];

$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'assessment.hasConfirmation' => Rule::in([0, 1, null]),
    'assessment.expiredDate' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($data) {
        return data_get($data, 'assessment.hasConfirmation') === 1;
    });
]);
```